# Implict super constructor

Tags: compiler-errors, processing

I have an implicit super constructor called button, but to class play it is undefined. I that's why I need an explicit super constructor.

Here's the code

```
class play extends Button {

}
```

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: You should post code as an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (for example, we have no idea what the `Button` class is), and you should post the **full text** of any errors you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting your terms mixed up.

The `Button` class is a **super class**, not a super constructor.

Since you haven't defined a constructor in your `play` class, it has an **implicit constructor**, so your class really looks like this:

```
class play extends Button {
   public play(){ //this is the implicit constructor
      super(); //this an implicit call to the super class's constructor
   }
}
```

It sounds like the `Button` class has a constructor that takes an argument, but your implicit constructor isn't passing in the required argument. That's what your error is telling you.

To fix that, you need to pass in whatever arguments the `Button` constructor needs.